# React Native Navigator отказывается выполнять метод renderScene

Tags: react-native

Код предельно простой:

```
 render() {
    return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Navigator style={{flex: 1}}
            renderScene={ this._renderScene.bind(this) }
            initialRoute={{ name: 'MainNews' }}/>
            </View>
        )

 }

 _renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if(route.name=='MainNews'){
        return
        <MainNews navigator={navigator}
        setProfData={this.setProfData.bind(this)}
        news={this.props.news}
        />
    }else if(route.name=='Profile'){
        return
        <Profile navigator={navigator}
        header={this.state.header}
        posts={this.state.posts}
        own={false}
        />
    }
}
```

Хотя этот компонент вложен в другой, в котором тоже есть навигатор, с таким же кодом, но работающий. И тот компонент вложен в еще один, тоже с навигатором, и еще... Tо есть, как минимум несколько работающих вложенных навигаторов с идентичными кодами. Этот не должен был стать исключением!

Но вижу я лишь белый экран.

Примечательно, что даже когда я без всяких условий прошу вернуть в этом методе несуществующий компонент

```
_renderScene(route, navigator) {
    return
    <Bla Bla Bla/>
}
```

React не кидает warning, хотя в рабочих навигаторах кидает! То есть, по логике он вообще не выполняет этот метод. И по этой же самой логике должен! Бедный мой мозг. В чем может быть дело?

P.S. Я пробовал вместо навигатора срендерить что-нибудь другое, и оно рендерится. Пробовал писать не только name, но component и index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменял дефолтный навигатор на aksonov router flux, потому что он сохраняет состояние компонентов при переключении между вкладками, например.
И что важно, вне зависимости от навигатора, он должен быть один на всё приложение! в index.js. А навигаторы, вложенные в компоненты других навигаторов, не комильфо.